# Matching multiple quotes in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match multiple quotes inside of a single sentence, for example the line:

`Hello "this" is a "test" example.`

This is the regex that I am using, but I am having some problems with it:

`/[^\.\?\!\'\"]{1,}[\"\'\“][^\"\'\“\”]{1,}[\"\'\“\”][^\.\?\!]{1,}[\.\?\!]/g`

What I am trying achieve with this regex is to find everything from the start of the last sentence until I hit quotes, then find the closing set and continue until either a `.?!`

The sample text that I am using to test with is from Call of Cthulhu:

> What seemed to be the main document was headed “CTHULHU CULT” in characters painstakingly printed to avoid the erroneous reading of a word so unheard-of. The manuscript was divided into two sections, the first of which was headed “1925—Dream and Dream Work of H. A. Wilcox, 7 Thomas St., Providence, R.I.”, and the second, “Narrative of Inspector John R. Legrasse, 121 Bienville St., New Orleans, La., at 1908 A. A. S. Mtg.—Notes on Same, & Prof. Webb’s Acct.” The other manuscript papers were all brief notes, some of them accounts of the queer dreams of different persons, some of them citations from theosophical books and magazines.

The issue comes on the line `The manuscript was...`. Does anyone know how to account for repeats like this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/7oFInG/1 didn't work.

Comment: You probably already know this, but just in case, [Regexr](http://regexr.com/) is a great tool for figuring out stuff like this.

Comment: Yeah that's what I have been using, I could do something similar to what I have above but searching for another set of quotes, but then I would end up having a very static regex.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do?: `[\"\'\“\”][^\"\'\“\”]+[\"\'\“\”]`

Comment: Are you wanting to match what's inside the quotes, or what's outside the quotes?

Comment: Sorry if the OP might be unclear. I am trying to take a paragraph and break it down into sentences. When there are quotes in the text I want to ignore the punctuation unless it is outside of quotes. The regex I have in the OP works only for the first case, but if a sentence has multiple quotes in it that contain punctuation inside of them it will break.

Comment: You might consider removing everything inside the quotes during processing before splitting on sentence boundaries.

Comment: Can you post your expected output from the example above? Are all of your quoted strings using unicode `“”` or can they contain normal `" '`?

Comment: Updating the OP, they can be normal quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one ignores [.?!] inside quotes. But cases like `Acct.” The nth` will be considered as a single sentence in this case. Probably a `.` is missing over there.

```js
var r = 'What seemed to be the main document was headed “CTHULHU.?! CULT” in characters painstakingly printed to avoid the erroneous reading of a word so unheard-of. The manuscript was divided into two sections, the first of which was headed “1925—Dream and Dream Work of H. A. Wilcox, 7 Thomas St., Providence, R.I.”, and the second, “Narrative of Inspector John R. Legrasse, 121 Bienville St., New Orleans, La., at 1908 A. A. S. Mtg.—Notes on Same, & Prof. Webb’s Acct.” The other manuscript papers were all brief notes, some of them accounts of the queer dreams of different persons, some of them citations from theosophical books and magazines.'
.split(/[“”]/g)
.map((x,i)=>(i%2)?x.replace(/[.?!]/g,''):x)
.join("'")
.split(/[.?!]/g)
.filter(x => x.trim()).map(x => ({
  sentence: x,
  quotescount: x.split("'").length - 1
}));

console.log(r);
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for, however I want to ignore punctuation inside of the quotes and only split when it is outside of quotations.

Looking at the regex I posted in the OP it should show the issue when it's run.

Comment: The answer is updated, but `Acct.” The ` will be considered as a single sentence. Also punctuations inside the quotes are removed, they can be restored if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this naive pattern:

```
/[^"'“.!?]*(?:"[^"*]"[^"'“.!?]*|'[^']*'[^"'“.!?]*|“[^”]*”[^"'“.!?]*)*[.!?]/
```

details:

```
/
[^"'“.!?]*          # all that isn't a quote or a punct that ends the sentence
(?:
    "[^"*]" [^"'“.!?]* 
  |
    '[^']*' [^"'“.!?]*
  |
    “[^”]*” [^"'“.!?]*
)*
[.!?]
/
```

If you want something more strong, you can emulate the "atomic grouping" feature, in particular if you are not sure that each opening quote has a closing quote (to prevent catastrophic backtracking):

```
/(?=([^"'“.!?]*))\1(?:"(?=([^"*]))\2"[^"'“.!?]*|'(?=([^']*))\3'[^"'“.!?]*|“(?=([^”]*))\4”[^"'“.!?]*)*[.!?]/
```

An atomic group forbids backtracking once closed. Unfortunately this feature doesn't exist in Javascript. But there's a way to emulate it using a lookahead that is naturally atomic, a capture group and a backreference:

```
(?>expr) => (?=(expr))\1
```